# When can a raider start riding in Kabaddi?

Tags: rules, kabaddi

Sometimes I see a raider waits for Umpire whistle to start raiding, but sometimes the raider just goes into raiding without waiting for the Umpire. What's the rule governing this?

I've seen some raiders just follow the opponent raider immediately and gets touch point. I don't understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A defender following a raider into the opposite court is called Pursuit. Defenders cannot pursue when they feel like it, there are some rules to be followed.

Link to [General Rules of Play](http://www.prokabaddi.com/prokabaddi-rules):

> viii. **After a raider has reached his court, the opponents shall send
>   their raider within 5 seconds.** Each side shall continue to send their
>   raider until the end of the game in this fashion. In case the raider
>   fails to start his raid within 5 seconds the team loses its chance to
>   raid and the opponent team is awarded a technical point.
>
> ix. **When a struggle takes place in a raid, on completion of such
>   raid,** Rule viii (above) will not be applicable. **The next raid will
>   start on the whistle of the referee after the out players have been
>   seated in the out box.**
>
> x. **If a raider, who is caught by one or more defenders, escapes from
>   their attempt to hold and reaches his court safely, he shall not be
>   pursued.**
>
> **a. Note: But if a raider touches one of more defenders and reaches his
>   court safely, he may be pursued.**

Per **rule ix.**, after raids in which a struggle took place, defender is not allowed to enter the opposite court until the referee blows the whistle, so he has to wait for the referee's whistle.

Per **rule x.** and **rule x. a.**, a defender may pursue a raider if raider returns to his court after touching one or more defenders, but not if he escaped from a struggle.

Other than these cases, a defending team has to send a raider within 5 seconds, they don't wait for the referee's signal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases here.

1. Raider can go immediately to the opposition court if the opponent raider had a empty ride.
2. But if the opponent raider gets touch point then the raider needs to wait till one person from opposition bench to join the defense. If he tries to raid before the opposition team member joins the team then the Umpire will whistles and asks the raider to start the raid again.